# Return a Single Json object as a String

Tags: java, json

I am trying to pass a single object:key-value as a JSON response. How to add a single JSON object and return it as a String:

```
{

"flag":"true"

}
```

Comment: do you use a library to generate json ?

Answer (score 1):

You may try below code

```
try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\"flag\":\"true\"}");
jsonObject.toString()
}catch (JSONException err){
     Log.d("Error", err.toString());
}
```

Comment: may refer the developer doc & library ref from here:https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json

Answer (score 1):

```
You can try using Maven Jackson databind dependency

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
   // Create a map for your key value json   
    Map<String,String> obj = new HashMap();
    obj.put("flag","true");
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    // Convert object into string
    String output = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(obj);
    return output;
```